# Toy identification: Transformer knockoff - Big Blue Head

Tags: character-identification, transformers, object-identification, toys

I know it's not a story I'm trying to identify, but it's the closest place I can find to ask. I'm trying to remember the name of a toy I had as a kid (in the late 1980s or early 1990s), and have never heard from since (and lost somewhere along the line).

It seemed to be a Transformers/GoBots/Etc knockoff. In "vehicle-mode" it was some sort of hovercar, with bulbous sides and a larger rounded central area (sort of like a Shelby Cobra). It was painted a mid to dark blue. As far as I remember, it didn't have wheels, but it may have had small ones built into the bottom to make the toy glide over surfaces.

I don't think it had a full "robot-mode"; instead, it had a head folded face-down in the area where you'd image a cockpit would be. That head could be flipped upward, and it had a rather angry humanoid face with red eyes, which leads me to believe it was one of the bad guys. I don't recall it having a body or limbs; it seemed to be made to connect with other toys of the same line to make one large Devastator/Megazord/Voltron-type robot, but I can't say for sure. Because of this, I think the character's name was something along the lines of the "Indomitable Head" (the adjective is probably wrong, but I'm pretty sure it was "-something- Head").

It was also (mostly) die-cast metal, if I recall correctly, which made it quite heavy for its size (approx. 3-4" in length), and somewhat unusual for toys in the 90s.

Anyway, hopefully someone remembers these toys and can remind me what they were... It's been so long I wonder if I've dreamt it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## It's [Fright Face](http://gbwiki.shoutwiki.com/wiki/Fright_Face) from GoBots!

[image: Fright Face - Vehicle and Robot forms]

Fright Face is a part of a larger robot called [Monsterous](http://gbwiki.shoutwiki.com/wiki/Monsterous), of whom he comprises the head. The packaging refers to him as the "Giant Monsterous Head" which is what I mistook for his name. The red cockpit on the vehicle flips up to reveal the [pseudo-]eponymous head - there's a photo of it [here on DeviantArt](https://www.deviantart.com/krytenmarkgen-0/art/GoBots-Fright-Face-854055117).

By the looks of the screenshots, I think I was mostly wrong about it being die cast metal, though the upper legs seem to be metal. It's also not as Shelby-esque as I remembered, but the general rounded-sides descriptions is generally true.

Thanks to DeeperMadness on Reddit, who was able to answer a copy of this question [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/ToyID/comments/tsid71/toy_id_blue_transformerlike_car_with_robot_head/).

Answer (score 4):

The physical description sounds like Scourge and the Sweeps, from *The Transformers* (1986):

[image: Scourge (G1) figure]

The Transformers Wiki page for [Scourge (G1)](http://transformers.wikia.com/wiki/Scourge_(G1)) shows this image and later variations of the character.

Comment: Definitely was not it though it's a good guess. My guy was nearly all blue (a very similar shade as Scourge). I'm pretty sure it wasn't an actual Transformer.

Comment: FYI, most of the community of that wiki moved to [a different site](https://tfwiki.net) in 2008, among other things because of how obnoxious the advertising on that platform is. It has [a much longer list of Scourge toys](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Scourge_(G1)/toys).